# Bash case not properly evaluating value

Tags: bash, switch-statement

### The Problem

I have a script that has a case statement which I'm expecting to execute based on the value of a variable. The case statement appears to either ignore the value or not properly evaluate it instead dropping to the default.

### The Scenario

I pull a specific character out of our server hostnames which indicates where in our environment the server resides. We have six different locations:

- Management(m): servers that are part of the infrastructure such as monitoring, email, ticketing, etc
- Development(d): servers that are for developing code and application functionality
- Test(t): servers that are used for initial testing of the code and application functionality
- Implementation(i): servers that the code is pushed to for pre-production evaluation
- Production(p): self-explanatory
- Services(s): servers that the customer needs to integrate that provide functionality across their project. These are separate from the Management servers in that these are customer servers while Management servers are owned and operated by us.

After pulling the character from the hostname I pass it to a case block. I expect the case block to evaluate the character and add a couple lines of text to our rsyslog.conf file. What is happening instead is that the case block returns the default which does nothing but tell the person building the server to manually configure the entry due to an unrecognized character.

I've tested this manually against a server I recently built and verified that the character I am pulling from the hostname (an 's') is expected and accounted for in the case block.

### The Code

```
# Determine which environment our server resides in
host=$(hostname -s)
env=${host:(-8):1}
OLDFILE=/etc/rsyslog.conf
NEWFILE=/etc/rsyslog.conf.new

# This is the configuration we need on every server regardless of environment
read -d '' common <<- EOF 
...
TEXT WHICH IS ADDED TO ALL CONFIG FILES REGARDLESS OF FURTHER CODE EXECUTION
SNIPPED
....
EOF

# If a server is in the Management, Dev or Test environments send logs to lg01
read -d '' lg01conf <<- EOF
# Relay messages to lg01
*.notice @@xxx.xxx.xxx.100
#### END FORWARDING RULE ####
EOF

# If a server is in the Imp, Prod or is a non-affiliated Services zone server send logs to lg02
read -d '' lg02conf <<- EOF
# Relay messages to lg02
*.notice @@xxx.xxx.xxx.101
#### END FORWARDING RULE ####
EOF

# The general rsyslog configuration remains the same; pull it out and write it to a new file
head -n 63 $OLDFILE > $NEWFILE

# Add the common language to our config file
echo "$common" >> $NEWFILE

# Depending on which environment ($env) our server is in, add the appropriate
# remote log server to the configuration with the $common settings.
case $env in
    m) echo "$lg01conf" >> $NEWFILE;;
    d) echo "$lg01conf" >> $NEWFILE;;
    t) echo "$lg01conf" >> $NEWFILE;;
    i) echo "$lg02conf" >> $NEWFILE;;
    p) echo "$lg02conf" >> $NEWFILE;;
    s) echo "$lg02conf" >> $NEWFILE;;
    *) echo "Unknown environment; Manually configure"
esac

# Keep a dated backup of the original rsyslog.conf file
cp $OLDFILE $OLDFILE.$(date +%Y%m%d)
# Replace the original rsyslog.conf file with the new version
mv $NEWFILE $OLDFILE
```

### An Aside

I've already determined that I can combine the different groups of code from the case block onto single lines (a total of two) using the | operator. I've listed it in the manner above since this is how it is coded while I'm having issues with it.

Comment: What do you get if you `echo $env` before the `case`?

Comment: There's too much context and too much irrelevant code in your question. Strip it down, and show examples of actual hostnames and the output of `echo "*${env}*"` before the case.

Comment: `<<-EOF` (ie, no space?) . Better to name the variable with a name not matching internals/external commands: `_env_` . And change the default : `*) echo "Unknown environment:${_env_}; Manually configure" ;;`  so that you see exactly what `${_env_}` (or `${env}` in your case) contained

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see what's wrong with your code. Maybe add another `;;` to the default clause. To find the problem add a `set -vx` as a first line. Will show you lots of debug information.